# Service doesn't print console.log

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-services

I need to create a service in my angular app so I do this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PropertiesNameService  {

  products: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('HI');
    this.http.get('****').subscribe(data => {
    //   console.log(data);
   });
  }
}
```

And in my app.module i do this:

```
import {PropertiesNameService} from './propertiesName/properties-name.service';
....

providers: [PropertiesNameService],
```

The problem is that when I start the app  and I open console I don't read "HI" . I use angular 8 anyone can help me?

Comment: Where did you use this service? Or better yet, where did you inject this service?

Comment: Since you are using the `providedIn: 'root'` feature of Injectable you shouldn't have to explicitly add it to the providers array in your AppModule. Does `ng build --aot --prod` output any errors?

Comment: Now the service is useless but I try in this way for see it app prints me the console.log

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heiywb?file=src/app/service.service.ts

Answer (score 5):

Seems like nobody's actually using that service so far. Have a component with `constructor (private propertiesNameService: PropertiesNameService) {}`, that'll instatiate the service and run its constructor.

Comment: No I need to use this service, but for try if  it works I leave alone the "console.log"

Comment: Is there any component that has `PropertiesNameService` injected? It can be `AppComponent`, or any other one.

Answer (score 1):

providedIn: 'root' specifies that Angular should provide the service in the root injector.

So:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  onHttp(){
    return   console.log('Message from service');
    // return this.http.get('****')
  }

}
```

And your app.component:

```
constructor(private service: ServiceService) { <---instantiate the service

 }

 onClick(){
   this.service.onHttp()
 }

 ngOnInit(){
   this.onClick()
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heiywb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope it helps!